# Should there be a question about 'Dismantling' for Witcher 3?

Tags: discussion

As this game gains traction the number of questions on it's tag is growing and I've noticed that a trend for specific item questions which all have a similar answer, in that the specific item can be sourced from the dismantling mechanic in the game.

- [Where can I find monster hair?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221708/where-can-i-find-monster-hair)
- [Where do I find monster carapace?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221150/where-do-i-find-monster-carapace)
- [What monsters do I kill for hides?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221112/what-monsters-do-i-kill-for-hides)

I'm curious on people's thoughts as to having a question about dismantling which these questions could point to in order to give a more general solution.

Or is there value in having specific key words in the questions and answers to help drive traffic from gamers searching for these specific items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was an old game where a complete wiki exists, a single question and answer about it would be possible. I don't think such a resource exists at this time, the game is still very new.

If we try this now, the answer would inevitably be incomplete, and it's much harder to get users to add to an old answer than to answer a new question. My guess would be that answer quality would be worse if we try to unify these questions.

Determining the scope would also be rather difficult in this case, it is not immediately obvious which items you get by dismantling and which you can just loot.

The number of crafting items is limited enough that I don't see a problem even if we get one question for every one. And we will likely get much fewer because many materials are easily found, and we tend to only get questions about those that are a bit harder to find.